# NodeJS Error: "SentHandleNotReceivedWarning: Handle did not reach the receiving process correctly"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I don't hope to receive any answer for this. Cause there's no result in Google either!

I'm getting this error while sending a `net.socket` object to a forked process:

```
(node:2101768) SentHandleNotReceivedWarning: Handle did not reach the receiving process correctly
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (node:internal/child_process:651:19)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:532:35)
    at emit (node:internal/child_process:938:14)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21)
```

Does anyone know the reason?

==============================

Additional info:

Socket is created like this
`const socket = new net.Socket({ fd, allowHalfOpen: true });`

And sending it to forked process:
`worker.send(data, socket);`

And in the case you wanna reproduce the porblem:

```
    const cluster = require('cluster');
    const cp = require('child_process');
    const fs = require('fs');
    const net = require('net');
    
    if(cluster.isPrimary) {//Primary

      const worker = cluster.fork();

      cp.execSync('mkfifo __test');
    
      fs.open(`__test`, fs.constants.O_RDONLY | fs.constants.O_NONBLOCK, async (e, fd) => {
        if(e) return console.log(e);
    
        const socket = new net.Socket({ fd, allowHalfOpen: true });
    
        worker.send('sending socket', socket);
    
      });
    
    } else {//worker
    
      process.on('message', (m, socket) => {
    
        console.log('Received in worker:', m, socket);
    
      });
    }
```

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce this problem?

Comment: This did not reproduce the issue for me.  FWIW: tested in docker, node:latest